# Calculation Performance (slow Plotting)

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

I have a functions, which is an Integral. It is exaclty this function

```
Zf[x_] := 2*I*NIntegrate[Exp[-y^2.0 + 2.0*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}];
```

Later I need to plot a graph of this function like this

```
Print["init time=", DateString[]]
Timing[Plot[Im[Zf[x]], {x, -2, 2}]]
Print["finish time=", DateString[]]
```

and it takes around 9 seconds.

but as final result I need to plot some more complicated functions, depends on this Zf like this.

```
f1[x_, p1_] := I*Im[Zf[x]] + p1*I*(1 + Zf[x]);
f2[x_, p1_, p2_] := 
  p1*(f1[x] + (2 + Zf[x])/ Conjugate[Zf[x]]) - 
   I*p2*(f1[x] - (2 - Zf[x])/ Conjugate[Zf[x]]);
```

Here p1 and p2 some parameters. and later I plot it again like this

```
Print["init time=", DateString[]]
Timing[Plot[Im[f1[x, 2]], {x, -2, 2}]]
Print["finish time=", DateString[]]

Print["init time=", DateString[]]
Timing[Plot[Im[f2[x, 1.35, 1.45]], {x, -2, 2}]]
Print["finish time=", DateString[]]
```

and plotting of f1 takes around 30 seconds, plotting of f2 takes 90 seconds.

If I replace NIntegrate to normal Integrate, it becomes much slower (I even cannot plot first graph in 10 minutes).

The problem is much bigger because finally I need dozens of graphs with comparation of all that functions and different parameters. Also I would like to change parameters quickly and compare the results.

```
Print["init time=", DateString[]]
Timing[Plot[{Im[Zf[x]], Im[f1[x, 2]], Im[f2[x, 1.35, 1.45]], 
   Im[f1[x, 3]], Im[f2[x, 2.35, 2.45]]}, {x, -2, 2}]]
Print["finish time=", DateString[]]
```

It takes 240 seconds.
Here is only 2 parameters. In real life it is much more complicated. I have around 10 parameters and functions more complicated than f1 and f2. It really takes hours.

Can I do something to improve performance of this kind of calculations?

Comment: Evaluate the integral outside the plotting - use *that* result within them. Doing so on your first example case results in a ~300X speed difference in a quick test...

Comment: `Zf[x]` has a nice closed form in terms of the Dawson integral; why not use that instead?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: 2500X faster on last example using CF result. Post it....

Comment: @ciao, bel already did it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is fast enough

```
p[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + 2*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}]
Zf[x_] := 2 I p[x]
f1[x_, p1_] := I*Im[Zf[x]] + p1*I*(1 + Zf[x]);
f2[x_, p1_, p2_] := p1*(f1[x] + (2 + Zf[x])/Conjugate[Zf[x]]) - 
                        I*p2*(f1[x] - (2 - Zf[x])/Conjugate[Zf[x]]);

Plot[Im[f1[x, 2]], {x, -2, 2}]
Plot[Im[f2[x, 1.35, 1.45]], {x, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: It works perfect!!!
Sorry, but I do not understand why it works much faster?

Because p[x] will be Dawson function like this 

1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] + I DawsonF[x]

or because of = sign instead of := ?

Or because p[x] after this line p[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + 2*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}] became something like array

Comment: It works perfect!
Sorry, but I do not understand why it works much faster?

Because p[x] will be Dawson function like this 

`1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] + I DawsonF[x]`

or because of = sign instead of := ?

Also I do not understand what really means
`p[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + 2*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}]`
?
I understand what is the differens between a=3*2 and a:=3*2. It is set and delayed set. But what it means in case of function? p[x] became something like a table with all data precalculated or what.

When it is better to use := and = for functions? Before I thought I must use := to plot it

Comment: @Zlelik read this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/193. And all the answers therein, BTW!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is much more clear.

Comment: Finally it was because of DawsonF[x] function. If I just replace Integrate to DawsonF[x], it became even more faster.